# watchkit WKAlertAction openSystemURL

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to show the User different Phone Numbers on Apple Watch and he clicks on one than phone call alert should appear. I'll do it like this but the Alert is just dismissed without call action:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
WKExtension *myExt = [WKExtension sharedExtension];
for (NSString *phone in arr) {
    NSString *tel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone];
    WKAlertAction *act = [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:tel style:WKAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(void){
        [myExt openSystemURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phone1]];
    }];
    [tempArray addObject:act];
}

NSString *titleMessage = @"Call";
NSString *textMessage = @"Please select the number you want to call.";
NSString *cancel = @"Cancel";

WKAlertAction *act = [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancel style:WKAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(void){

}];
[tempArray addObject:act];

[self presentAlertControllerWithTitle:titleMessage message:textMessage preferredStyle:WKAlertControllerStyleAlert actions:tempArray];
```

Buttons are shown as expected and the Handler is also called with the correct Phone Number. But it does not openSystemURL. Does somebody know why and how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: This is known as bug. See forum post here: forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4385

Comment: I see. But if I do not embed the openSystemURL in WKAlertAction rather use it as a IBAction from a Button it does work. The behavior than is that it shows this: http://cl.ly/image/3f0K2u1G041C (But when I use openSystemURL in WKAlertAction Handler it just dismiss the Alert and nothing happens). My fear is now that User clicks on a phone number and nothing happens --> worst case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add "tel" scheme ,Use below code :

```
[WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"tel" style:WKAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(void){
[[WKExtension sharedExtension]openSystemURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",@"YOUR NUMBER"]]];
 }];
```

[About Apple URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899)